# Can't open file font error in xhtml2pdf template - django

Tags: python, django, xhtml2pdf

During handling of the above exception ([Errno 13] Permission denied: ttf'), another exception occurred: django

style type="text/css">
@font-face {font-family: RTLFont; src: url('F:\MyProjects\my_app\app\static\app\fonts\font_name.ttf')}

```
    body {
        font-weight: 200;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-family: RTLFont;
    }
@page {
    size: a4 portrait;
    @frame header_frame {           /* Static Frame */
        -pdf-frame-content: header_content;
        left: 50pt; width: 512pt; top: 50pt; height: 40pt;
    }
    @frame content_frame {          /* Content Frame */
        left: 50pt; width: 512pt; top: 90pt; height: 632pt;
    }
    @frame footer_frame {           /* Another static Frame */
        -pdf-frame-content: footer_content;
        left: 50pt; width: 512pt; top: 772pt; height: 20pt;
    }
}
.text-header-primary {
    color: red;
}
```

getting me an error:
TTFError at /api/visits/print
Can't open file "C:\Users\User~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmptiuhy3pp.ttf"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.